# При попытке добавить материал на курс отображается ошибка "Обнаружено неверное значение ответа."

Tags: moodle

При попытке добавить элемент или ресурс на курс, отображается в модальном окне "Произошла ошибка. Обнаружено неверное значение ответа.". В чем может быть причина, по факту moodle только установлен и ничего в нем не наклацано